# How to handle styling in Grails i18n text?

Tags: grails, internationalization

I am internationalizing my Grails (2.4.2) app and stumbled across a use case I hadn't previously considered. I need to turn:

```
<p>The quick <b>brown fox jumps</b> over the fence.</p>
```

Into:

```
<p><g:message code="example.text" /></p>
```

However, as you can see, in the middle of this sentence is styling/formatting HTML in the form of `<b>...</b>` tags. I haven't ran into this before, and I'm kind of stumped. To me it seems that formatting/styling instructions don't belong in i18n properties files like so:

```
# messages.properties
example.text=The quick <b>brown fox jumps</b> over the fence.
```

So, I now have a rather ugly looking:

```
<p><g:message code="example.text.1" /> <b><g:message code="example.text.2" /></b> <g:message code="example.text.3" />.</p>
```

And:

```
# messages.properties
example.text.1=The quick
example.text.2=brown fox jumps
example.text.3=over the fence.
```

But this just feels silly. So I ask: **What is the Grails way of handling styling inside i18n text?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about it.  For simple text emphasis (bold, italic, underline) it is perfectly fine to put the necessary html code in the i18n property file.